# Как правильно создать таблицу в phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

Помогите кто может! Второй день мучаюсь с базой данных и таблицами в phpmyadmin.
Если быть точнее, то проблема в том, что я не могу заполнить таблицы данными, при сохранении мне выдают вот такую ошибку:
[image]

Подскажите, что нужно делать, чтоб избежать этой ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл ответ на свой вопрос: оказывается, при создании как БД, так и таблиц с ячейками, нужно следить, чтоб у них было одинаковое расширение, в Callation указать кодировку, а в type установить MyISAM. 
Мне это помогло.